# Can't launch JetBrains Toolbox on macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: macos, applications, spotlight

I'm trying to launch the JetBrains Toolbox, but it seems I can't. When I launch via Spotlight search, nothing appears to happen. But when I try to run the launcher manually from the command line, this happens:

```
> /Applications/JetBrains\ Toolbox.app/Contents/jetbrains-toolbox-launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/jetbrains-toolbox-launcher
2019-06-07 10:08:56.436 jetbrains-toolbox-launcher[47157:731143] Staring wrapper...
2019-06-07 10:08:56.437 jetbrains-toolbox-launcher[47157:731143] Running app file:///Applications/Calculator.app/ with arguments (
)
```

and then, indeed, the Calculator launches.

I just upgraded to macOS Mojave 10.14.5 and I believe the app was working before the upgrade. I recently accidentally deleted large parts of `/usr/local` with an inadvertent `rm -rf /usr/local` (non-sudo). I interrupted it fairly quickly and was able to restore my `Homebrew` apps to apparently-working order by re-linking all of them. I successfully launched the Toolbox application once after that happened, but was unable to do so again.

Unfortunately, I don't remember for sure how I installed Toolbox, but I *think* I installed it directly from the web rather than with `brew cask`.

I can see the Toolbox app icon in Launchpad, and just as when launching from Spotlight Search, nothing seems to happen when I try to launch it from there.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) How did you install JetBrains toolbox? Direct download or via Homebrew Cask? Can you see the JetBrains Toolbox icon in Launchpad?

Comment: Thanks! I have answered those questions and added an additional piece of info that may actually be fairly crucial.

Comment: You can try reinstalling the app. First of all install [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (you can install it via Homebrew Cask by running, `brew cask install appcleaner`). Then using AppCleaner completely remove JetBrains Toolbox. Now re-install Toolbox using Homebrew Cask by running `brew cask install jetbrains-toolbox`.

Comment: @NimeshNeema It looks like I was mistaken, and the Toolbox was being launched as an icon in the little icon-tray on the upper-right of the desktop (by the clock; I'm not sure what that's called). I'm still not sure why the calculator gets launched, though.